# Does the C++ std library have some more environmental-dependencies than the winAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, frameworks, std

I know the win API is the ground-floor thing in Windows. When a computer has a Windows system installed, so long as the system version matches the API requirement, API functions can work.

But, for example, .NET requires the .NET framework to be installed, so it has more environmental-dependencies.

Then, does the C++ std library require something like the framework, or is the required thing already pre-installed in almost every computer?

Comment: Ever had to install something called the "Microsoft Visual C++ runtime"? That is the "required thing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally yes, on Windows the C++ std library is a DLL, and no it's **not** part of Windows.

In case of **Visual C++** you need a corresponding [Visual C++ Redistributable package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads), which will install files like `MSVCP140.DLL` etc.

**MinGW** uses GCC/libstdc++ DLLs like `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, etc.

If you want to avoid having to install these files, there's often an option to link your program *statically* (e.g. `/MT` for VC++ and `-static` for MinGW), in which case the needed CRT parts will be embedded inside your binary/executable (at the expense of its size and security patches lifecycle).